# usage of the handler of async_accept

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I write my own function named asyncAccept to encapsulate the standard boost::asio::ip::acceptor::async_accept, but problems occurred when I run my program.
An error was thrown and it prints "argument invalid". It seems that the expression has something wrong:

```
boost::bind(handle_accept, placeholders::error, socket, tcp_version, port_num, handler));
```

I wonder what's the problem.
Complete codes are attached below. My mother tongue is not English, so please be patient a bit~~
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
----------------------------------------asyncAccept.cpp-------------------------------
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include "impl/asyncAccept.h"

using namespace boost::asio;

namespace asyncTcp{

error_type illegal_version = -1;
error_type accept_error = -2;
const int TCPV4 = 4;
const int TCPV6 = 6;

io_service io_server;
ip::tcp::acceptor _acceptor(io_server);

ip::tcp::socket _socket(io_server);
void *servSocket = &_socket;

void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error, void* socketPtr, const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num, callback handler);

void init_acceptor(const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num);

//bind a socket with a port
void asyncAccept(void* socketPtr, const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num, callback handler){

    if (tcp_version != TCPV4 && tcp_version != TCPV6)
        throw illegal_version;

    init_acceptor(tcp_version, port_num);

    ip::tcp::socket *socket = reinterpret_cast<ip::tcp::socket*>(socketPtr);

    _acceptor.async_accept((*socket),
        boost::bind(handle_accept, placeholders::error, socket, tcp_version, port_num, handler));

    return;
}

void handle_accept(const boost::system::error_code& error, void* socketPtr, const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num, callback handler){
    if (!error){
        //cycle server
        handler();

        asyncAccept(socketPtr, tcp_version, port_num, handler);
    }
    else
        throw boost::system::system_error(error);
}

void init_acceptor(const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num){
    if (TCPV4 == tcp_version){
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v4(), port_num);
        _acceptor.open(ip::tcp::v4());
        _acceptor.bind(ep);
    }
    else{
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v6(), port_num);
        _acceptor.open(ip::tcp::v6());
        _acceptor.bind(ep);
    }
}

void run_server(){
    io_server.run();

    return;
}

}//namespace



-----------------------------------impl/asyncAccept.h----------------------------------
#ifndef SERV_SOCKET_H
#define SERV_SOCKET_H

namespace asyncTcp{

#ifndef CALL_BACK
#define CALL_BACK
typedef void (*callback)();
#endif

#ifndef ERROR_TYPE
#define ERROR_TYPE
typedef int error_type;
#endif

extern error_type illegal_version;
extern error_type accept_error;
//extern void* io_server;
extern void* servSocket;
extern const int TCPV4;
extern const int TCPV6;

void asyncAccept(void* socketPtr, const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num, callback handler);

void run_server();
}

#endif /* SERV_SOCKET_H */
```

Comment: Why do you pass pointer to object as `void *` and then `reinterpret_cast` it? It's a bad style.

Comment: @herbert: did my answer below work for you?

Comment: @Simon：yes,thanks a lot!

Comment: @IgorR.:because I don't want to expose the value type in the boost library.And I don't know other methods....

Comment: What do you mean? The caller of your `asyncAccept` function would pass `tcp::socket *` anyway, right? So, this type will be exposed to him. Am I missing something?

Comment: @IgorR.:In the asyncAccept.cpp I defined "ip::tcp::socket _socket(io_server);void *servSocket = &_socket;" and the caller must include the "impl/asyncAccept.h" in which I "externed void* servSocket". And then the caller can use the void type of socket as an argument of asyncAccept and in the func I reinterpret_cast it to the tcp::socket* type. I know it's stupid but I don't know any other way to hide the tcp::socket type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the `boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor` into the listen state. This can be done by calling `boost::asio::ip::tcp::listen()`. Like this:

```
void init_acceptor(const int tcp_version, unsigned short port_num){
    if (TCPV4 == tcp_version){
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v4(), port_num);
        _acceptor.open(ip::tcp::v4());
        _acceptor.bind(ep);
    }
    else{
        ip::tcp::endpoint ep(ip::tcp::v6(), port_num);
        _acceptor.open(ip::tcp::v6());
        _acceptor.bind(ep);
    }
    _acceptor.listen();
}
```

Explanation:
If the server socket is not in listen state when calling the underlying `accept(..)` function of the socket API, an error is signaled, that the passed socket is not valid for finishing the requested operation (in our case accept a client socket).

Comment: Great!The exception disappear!Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @herbert: Then you can flag this as solved by checking the tick. :-)